# Why did "The A-Team" movie not use the original TV series theme song?

Tags: soundtrack, the-a-team, the-a-team-2010

I've also seen this kind of situation in the *Miami Vice* and *Starsky & Hutch* movies. The producers didn't use the original TV series theme song for the movie.

Is there any legal reason for this?

Comment: So is this just about *The A-Team* or all the other movies, too? In the latter case, you might want to adjust the question title (and in the former case the question body and tags). But in that case the question might also be a little broad.

Comment: __[But they did use it!](https://youtu.be/IhdEKY1b0tk?t=43)__ (Youtube link)

Comment: Makes me want to ask why the Tom Cruise War of the Worlds didn't use the Jeff Wayne theme...

Comment: Related question: why did the A-Team stop using the original A-Team theme song in season 5? That synth version was terrible

Answer (score 6):

Legal? No. 20th Century Fox just wanted an [updated](https://theboombox.com/just-blaze-remixes-a-team-theme-song/) version of it. They commissioned [Just Blaze](https://rapradar.com/2010/05/18/just-blaze-a-team-theme-song-remix/) to re-write it, but they could have just as easily used the original theme. As Oliver C pointed out [in the comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71392/why-did-the-a-team-movie-not-use-the-original-tv-series-theme-song#comment115437_71392), they did use the unchanged version within the movie.